Sent Pepe to ETH address on Coinbase and is not showing
I have sent Pepe coin from MetaMask to ETH address on Coinbase and is not reflecting on my Coinbase account.
On MetaMask is showing that the transaction was successful.

CEXs, like Coinbase, use a set of smart contracts to handle user balances, as opposed to each user having their own keypair that they may use for any ERC20 token (Like you are probably familiar with since EOAs behave this way).
That being said, your Ethereum mainnet address for PEPE is not the same as your Ethereum mainnet address for ETH, so if you sent PEPE to your ETH address, it is likely lost.
I know it can be hard but your best options at this point are to:

Reach out to Coinbase support.
Learn from this mistake so that you don't repeat it in the future.

If you sent your PEPE to your PEPE address on the same chain, and have already verified the address is correct, then definitely reach out to the Coinbase support email/number, or check out their help page.
